# Saving data failed on Symfony2 with persist method

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.1

I had a problem while saving data of conflict entity and it failed every time the methods is called.

```
$em->persist($conflict);
```

return back a blank screen and show a string 'persist'. I don't know how to solve it as I am new to symfony2.

Here is my sample code on create conflict controller.

```
public function createAction() {
    $conflict = new Conflict();
    $form = $this->createForm(new ConflictType(), $conflict, array(
        "container" => $this->container,
        "em" => $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager()
    ));

    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $form->bindRequest($request);
    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $conflict->setAwardDeadlineCurrent($conflict->getAwardDeadlineInit());
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
        $em->persist($conflict);
        $em->flush();
        $request->getSession()->setFlash("notice", "Case has been created");
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl("acf_case_conflict_edit", array("id" => $conflict->getId())));
    }
    return $this->render("ACFCaseBundle:Conflict:new.html.twig", array("form" => $form->createView()));
}
```

Comment: Do you have any eventlistener / event subscriber? Does this entity "conflict" have any method a"PostUpdate" "PrePersist" etc? If this is the only code you wrote, looks all right (maybe something funky on the form "conflictType") so it must be something about our symfony2 installation

Comment: agree with @Francesc ... sounds like die(); to test if some part of the code was reached

Answer (score 1):

There may be few concern:

If u r using latest version of symfony i. e. (Symfony2.2 or more latest) then :

```
$form->bindRequest($request);
```

should be :

```
$form->handleRequest($request);
```

and also in return rendering line

```
 return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl("acf_case_conflict_edit", array("id" => $conflict->getId())));
```

You are rendering just your id while you should pass a object to render the all field of object ..
It may be like this :

```
return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl("acf_case_conflict_edit", array("conflict" => $conflict)));
```

also i do't understand mandatory to pass the

```
  array(
    "container" => $this->container,
    "em" => $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager()
)
```

in your form creation like

```
   $form = $this->createForm(new ConflictType(), $conflict, array(
    "container" => $this->container,
    "em" => $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager()
   ));
```

It may be like this

```
   $form = $this->createForm(new ConflictType(), $conflict);
```

Comment: Thank I will check your suggestion and let you know